# Migration from Jetpack Image CDN to Cloudflare

Tags: seo, wordpress, cdn, cloudflare

Like most of the Wordpress site owners, I have been using Jetpack's Image CDN for delivering images across the world on my site. Lately, I came across [this article](https://michaelkummer.com/tech/blogging/jetpack-photon-seo/) stating that there is no harm in delivering images from different domain (i0.wp.com, Jetpack's domain) than ours because Jetpack response includes canonical URL of the original image on my server, and that's what Google uses to index. Although this make sense, but I observe Google is indexing images from Jetpack domain and NOT from my domain.

Now my question is, If I want to migrate from Jetpack to Cloudflare image CDN then would it hurt me in the SEO as it doesn't appear that Google is using canonical url to index instead of Jetpack's url. I don't want to be tied to the Jetpack's url for my images. Cloudflare allows me to serve images from CDN with my domain url. Also, I can't cache invalidate my images on Jetpack CDN, so sort of stuck here.

Any guidance for the seamless migration to Cloudflare without hurting SEO is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare doesn't change your image URL at all like jetpack. As long as it will serve the original URL, you don't need canonical with Cloudflare.
Cloudflare will serve your website content like nothing in the middle at all. Everything served under your domain and that's is absolutely fine. You shouldn't worry about it!

Comment: yes, I know that. My question was what happens to images that are already indexed by google which are on jetpack domain? What Seo impact it will have once i switch to cloudflare ?

Comment: as long as those images contain canonical link to the original image URL, cloudflare CDN is not going to arise duplicate content issue. So nothing to worry about.